# Jsp and Servlets in same HTML page

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I want to develop a login HTML page  that will contain both signup and sign-in buttons . In the HTML page at run time i have the option to select any of the button (sign-in/sign-up). On clicking on the signup the page should redirect to a Signup JSP program and by clicking on sign-in page the page should redirect to a login Servlet program . Now The problem is that which page(JSP/SERVLET) I have to mention in action method of form in html page. ? How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You can just insert text

example:

```
<a href="http://urlToSignInPage">Sign In</a>
<a href="http://urlToSignUpPage">Sign Up</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be simple hyperlink [GET], You don't need to submit form for that

```
<a href="urlToSignInPage"><!--sign in button code --></a>



<a href="urlToSignUpPage"><!--sign up button code --></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use button then you have to go through `jQuery` or `javascript` events such as onClick of the button. here is few example. exactly what you need. You dont need to do that by  form action submit.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function open_win()
{
    window.open("http://yoururl.com");
    /*or 
    window.location.href = "/yourpathToPageOrServletIfany/yourfiel.jsp.html.phpOrYourServletMapping";
    */
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Open Window" onclick="open_win()">

</body>
</html>
```

the same thing is possible with the jquery `$('#buttonId').click(function(){...in here ...});`

Comment: Why exactly is JS/jQuery necessary? You could for instance also have used `<form action="yourSignInServlet" target="_blank"><input type="submit" value="Sign In" /></form>` if you need to have per se a submit button which opens a GET request in a new window  (which the OP didn't exactly ask for btw). Your JS/jQuery approach doesn't degrade gracefully as well (i.e. it fails to work when the client has JS disabled, like most of current mobile clients).

Comment: @BalusC : This could be other way out to do the same thing.but in case you don't want to submit form.All I mean is this is the one possible way with assuming a standard healthy browser.